# How to initialize a Pydantic object from field values given by position instead of name?

Tags: python, iterable, pydantic

I am not able to find a simple way how to initialize a Pydantic object from field values given by position (for example in a list instead of a dictionary) so I have written class method `positional_fields()` to create the required dictionary from an iterable:

```py
from typing import Optional, Iterable, Any, Dict
from pydantic import BaseModel


class StaticRoute(BaseModel):
    if_name: str
    dest_ip: str
    mask: str
    gateway_ip: str
    distance: Optional[int]
    
    @classmethod
    def positional_fields(cls, values: Iterable) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        return dict(zip(cls.__fields__, values))


input_lines = """
  route ab 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 10.220.196.23 1
  route gh 10.0.2.61 255.255.255.255 10.220.198.38 1
""".splitlines()

for line in input_lines:
    words = line.split()
    if words and words[0] == 'route':
        sroute = StaticRoute(**StaticRoute.positional_fields(words[1:]))
        print(sroute)
```

```
if_name='ab' dest_ip='10.0.0.0' mask='255.0.0.0' gateway_ip='10.220.196.23' distance=1
if_name='gh' dest_ip='10.0.2.61' mask='255.255.255.255' gateway_ip='10.220.198.38' distance=1
```

Is there a more straightforward way of achieving this?

My method expects the `__fields__` dictionary to have keys in the order the fields were defined in the class. I am not sure if this is guaranteed (assuming Python 3.6+).

Comment: It seems to be intentional that reading of positional fields is not supported: [Add support for positional arguments #116](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/116)

Comment: Related question: [Allow positional arguments for BaseModel pydantic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73156982/320437)

Answer (score 2):

How about using [dataclasses](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/dataclasses/) instead? Something like:

```
from typing import Optional

from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class StaticRoute:
    if_name: str
    dest_ip: str
    mask: str
    gateway_ip: str
    distance: Optional[int]


words = "route if_name dest_ip mask gateway_ip 10".split()
print(StaticRoute(*words[1:])

# StaticRoute(if_name='if_name', dest_ip='dest_ip', mask='mask', gateway_ip='gateway_ip', distance=10)
```

Comment: Now I notidced that it is `dataclass` from Pydantic. I have to check what are all the differences from the `BaseModel` which is being preferred in the documentation.

Comment: I would like to remove my old upvote but because of StackOverflow explicit limitations I am not able to do that :( Pydantic `dataclass` is simply not what you normally want when using Pydantic. It has limitations when compared to `BaseModel`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of a [custom RootType](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#custom-root-types) and [NamedTuple](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#namedtuple), like so:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import NamedTuple, Optional


class StaticRouteTuple(NamedTuple):
    if_name: str
    dest_ip: str
    mask: str
    gateway_ip: str
    distance: Optional[int]


class StaticRoute(BaseModel):
    __root__: StaticRouteTuple

    @property
    def route(self) -> StaticRouteTuple:
        return self.__root__


input_lines = """
  route ab 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 10.220.196.23 1
  route gh 10.0.2.61 255.255.255.255 10.220.198.38 1
""".splitlines()

for line in input_lines:
    words = line.split()
    if words and words[0] == "route":
        sroute = StaticRoute.parse_obj(words[1:]).route
        print(sroute)
```

If you don't want to use a custom RootType you can use instead [`pyandic.parse_obj_as`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#parsing-data-into-a-specified-type), example:

```py
from pydantic import parse_obj_as
sroute = parse_obj_as(StaticRouteTuple, words[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

The class method [`BaseModel.parse_obj()`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#helper-functions) returns an object instance initialized by a dictionary. We can create a similar class method `parse_iterable()` which accepts an iterable instead.

```py
from typing import Optional, Iterable, Any, Dict
from pydantic import BaseModel


class BaseModelExt(BaseModel):
    @classmethod
    def parse_iterable(cls, values: Iterable):
        return cls.parse_obj(dict(zip(cls.__fields__, values)))

    
class StaticRoute(BaseModelExt):
    if_name: str
    dest_ip: str
    mask: str
    gateway_ip: str
    distance: Optional[int]


input_lines = """
  route ab 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 10.220.196.23 1
  route gh 10.0.2.61 255.255.255.255 10.220.198.38 1
""".splitlines()

for line in input_lines:
    words = line.split()
    if words and words[0] == 'route':
        sroute = StaticRoute.parse_iterable(words[1:])
        print(sroute)
```

Note: *We are still missing a confirmation if the order of `BaseModel.__fields__` is guaranteed.*

Comment: Note that this would not validate if the number of items in the iterable are more than the number of fields in the model

Comment: @whatthe Unfortunately it will not fail. Zipping iterables of different lengths produces an iterator of the shortest length and ignores the excessive items. (`list(zip((1,2),(5,6,7))) == [(1,5),(2,6)]`) --- In Python 3.10+ we can add the `strict=True` argument to `zip()` to make it fail if the iterables are not of equal lengths but this would make the `StaticRoute.distance` attribute non-optional. We would need to implement our own variant of `zip()` with asymmetric strictness to allow optional attributes and fail for excessive items.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Pydantic `Field` support [`kw_only` attribute](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/fields/#dataclass-constraints) that will allow you to create your model with positional fields:

```py
from pydantic import Field
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class MyModel:
    a: str = Field(kw_only=False)
    b: str = Field(kw_only=False)


model_arg = MyModel("test", "model")
model_kw = MyModel("test", b="model")
model_kw2 = MyModel(a="test", b="model")

print(model_arg, model_kw, model_kw2)
```

Comment: Thanks but this is a dataclass compatibility feature. `pydantic.dataclasses` have limited functionality compared to `pydantic.BaseModel` also `kw_only` is not enabled by default so using `Field(kw_only=False)` is redundant here. See: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/dataclasses/

Answer (score 0):

This solution is fully Pydantic.

The input is some string that is returned via a serial connection, which I parse into the model by order.

Although this works, I don't know if the risk is worth the savings of code. If a future developer messes the order of the fields in the Model, it would be hard to debug the issue.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


class IrisResponse(BaseModel):
    code: str
    char_t: str
    value: str
    char_s: str
    num1: str
    num2: str
    num3: str
    num4: str

    def __init__(self, value: str):
        super().__init__(**dict(zip(IrisResponse.__fields__, value.split())))


out = "03: T        90000 S= 0001 0001 0000 1000 "
result = IrisResponse(out)
print(result.__repr__())
```

---

Output:

```
IrisResponse(code='03:', char_t='T', value='90000', char_s='S=', num1='0001', num2='0001', num3='0000', num4='1000')
```