# Allow positional arguments for BaseModel pydantic

Tags: python, pydantic

I have a class with all the necessary parameters. But, for **init** function, it asks for keyword arguments, and does not accept positional arguments. So, my question is: is there something I can change in config of pydantic.BaseModel to allow positional arguments?

Here is an example of my class:

```
class Foo(BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: Optional[str]
    c: Optional[float]
```

And when I init the class, I need to pass keyword arguments:
[image: Image of a class parameters]

So, I cannot initialize the class like this:

```
Foo(1,2,2.5)
# instead, I should init it like this:
Foo(a=1,b=2,c=2.5)
```

So, I need to be able to pass positional keywords to the class. Is it possible?

Comment: See this question with some suggestions: [How to initialize a Pydantic object from field values given by position instead of name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69711914/320437)

Answer (score 6):

Example of override `__init__` method with type hint which works in pycharm

```
class Foo(BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: Optional[str]
    c: Optional[float]
    
    def __init__(self, a: int,
                 b: Optional[str] = None,
                 c: Optional[float] = None,
                 **kwargs) -> None:
        super(Foo, self).__init__(a=a, b=b, c=c, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pydantic objects don't support positional arguments unless you implement it yourself as Arseniy Lebedev suggest.

Why is that ? [Here are some reasons](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/116):

- when you have lot of fields - it would be very easy to add another field into a model and suddenly all code which assumes fields have a given position breaks silently
- annotation only fields mean the order of pydantic model fields different from that in code.

```py
import json
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional

class Foo(BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: Optional[str]
    c: Optional[float]
```

You can give Pydantic every key you want to init your model with (what you did):

```py
Foo(a=1,b="2",c=2.5)
```

Or you can use a json:

```py
json_raw = '{"a": 1, "b": "2", "c": 3}'
some_dict = json.loads(json_raw)
my_foo = Foo(**some_dict)
```

or mix of both:

```py
json_raw = '{"a": 1, "b": "2"}'
some_dict = json.loads(json_raw)
my_foo = Foo(**some_dict, c=3)
```

Comment: Are there any other library similar to pydantic for the same thing but which accepts positional arguments? Or I will have to implement it myself?

Comment: I found workaround for it, i created an init function in my class, which will get all positional arguments and turn it into keyword arguments by using __fields__ from pydantic.BaseModel. But, for my init function, typehints are not displayed... Can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use this code:

```
def model_from_args(model, args):
    return model(**{field: arg for field, arg in zip(model.model_fields, args)})
```

The possibility of breaking code, after changes of a model, is very high.